# Single ListView inside a CardView

Tags: android, fragment, cardview

I have a screen requirement like this:

[image: Screen Requirement]

But I cannot get it to work like that. I ended up making a View like this:

[image: Actual]

I am using a CardView. The List content is dynamically expanding.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblProductName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Product Name"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblProductQuantity"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="99"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I make my screen to look the same as the required screen?

Comment: post your codes

Comment: Show your XML .

Comment: @KingofMasses I have edited my post and included my xml.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try like below code in xml , put your ListView inside CardView;

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:background="@color/color"
        android:id="@+id/cv1"
        card_view:cardElevation="3.5dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#fff"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

           <ListView
            android:id="@+id/study_level_list"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: I'll try. Thanks.

Comment: It worked!! Thanks. I just have to search about populating a customListView on a Fragment.

Comment: I have less than 15 reputations as of now, my upvote will not reflect. (According to Stackoverflow).

Answer (score 1):

Add Your Recyclerview inside card view

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cv1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@color/color"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#fff"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="3.5dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recylerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

and change your adapter layout as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblProductName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Product Name"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblProductQuantity"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="99"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your List View inside Card View

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
            card_view:contentPadding="10dp">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```